# Hiding and showing HTML elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having trouble showing and hiding a tag on my page.

When the page loads I have

```
<a id="mylink" class="hiddenClass">...</a>
```

hiddenClass has display: none

When a certain event occurs, I use javascript to try and show the element in block style

```
document.getElementById("mylink").display = "block";
```

It doesn't show it.  When I alert document.getElementById("mylink").display it says block.. but it's not showing.

How can I fix this..? And, in general, what is the best way to show and hide DOM elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do:

```
document.getElementById("mylink").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove that class

```
document.getElementById("mylink").className = '';
```